# I need to rename multiple files by removing the multiple dates prefixing the files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, debian

I accidently renamed all of my files by adding a prefix multiple times to each directory. I have tried the "rename" command and some pea[image]l scripting but I still can't resolve name changes. Any ideas on how to remove all the dates at once so that I just have directory?

Example

mv 2020-11-30-2020-11-30...2020-11-30-Documents Documents/

Comment: *I have tried*. Please show the code. Also give the expected result and actual result. Also, do not post text as images. Copy it directly as text into the question.

Comment: pls provide input and expected output in the code block.

Comment: Which variant of the `rename` command do you have — the Perl version or 'the other one'.  With the Perl version, you should be able to use `rename 's/2020-11-30-//g' 2020-11-30-*` to do the job.  It would leave you with names like `buddy`, `Cmnd_Alias`, `Documents`, `Downloads`, …

Answer (score 1):

> mv 2020-11-30-2020-11-30...2020-11-30-Documents Documents/

Assuming your filenames don't contain linebreak, quotes. or other special chars:

```
\ls -1|sed 's/.*-\(.*\)/mv "&" "\1"/'
```

You can check the output produced by the above command, if it looks good, pipe the output to `|sh`

NOTE: the backslash before `ls` is for ignoring your alias if you had ls alias.

Comment: This works as long as none of the base names itself contains a dash.  If a file was `2020-11-30-Important-File` (with the date repeated a few more times), this `sed` script would leave you with `File` and not `Important-File`.  Hopefully, there wasn't also `2020-11-30-Unimportant-File` that also got renamed to `File` — because then the important file got overwritten by the unimportant one.

Answer (score 0):

These commands both worked:

```
ls -1 | sed 's/.*-\(.*\)/mv "&" "\1"/'
rename 's/2020-11-30-//g' 2020-11-30-*
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which does not require the use of `regex`. Based on [`vimv`](https://github.com/thameera/vimv) and the multi-cursor edition in `Vscode`:

Both packages are shipped in most Linux distributions:

```
apt install vimv codium
```

Open a terminal and setup codium as your editor: `export EDITOR="codium -w"`

Browse the terminal in the appropriate folder and type `vimv`. Hit enter

Vscodium opens, and shows the list of files and folders

Add cursors where you want. Quoting [from the doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_multiple-selections-multicursor):

> You can add secondary cursors (rendered thinner) with `Alt+Click`. Another
> common way to add more cursors is with `Shift+Alt+Down` or `Shift+Alt+Up`
> that insert cursors below or above.

Delete whatever you want, **save the file**, and exit

The files and folders should be renamed accordingly

Checkout [the website of vimv](https://github.com/thameera/vimv) for more informations and screencasts